# JavaScript window.onresize AND less than 1024 wide

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a fixed left DIV that I would like to hide for window widths less that 1024, which I can do. But I'm not sure how to hide it if the user resizes to less than 1024?

This is what I currently have, but doesn't work if the users resizes the window to less than 1024.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {
    $(".leftnav").css({
    "width": "0px"
});
    
}
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should work (http://jsfiddle.net/PPTXJ/ <-- resize the right frame!) :

```
$(window).resize(toggleNav);
$(document).ready(toggleNav);

function toggleNav() {

 if($(window).width() < 1024)
    $(".leftnav").hide();
 else
    $(".leftnav").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    // your code here
}
```